# Solidity Fallback Function Gas Limit

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, fallback, evm

I am a bit confused with the fallback function in Solidity using Remix IDE, as far as I understand, the fallback function is limited to 2300 gas. However, when I call the fallback function by using the 'Transact' button in Remix, it does not fail even though it uses more than 2300 gas.

```
// let anyone send ether to the contract
fallback() external payable { 
    require(msg.data.length == 0);
}
```

Am I misunderstanding how fallback functions work and is my implementation of the fallback secure for when I want users to be able to send Ether to the contract? I also check the length of the data to ensure the function isn't used for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

> *In the worst case, if a payable fallback function is also used in place of a receive function, it can only rely on 2300 gas being available (see receive Ether function for a brief description of the implications of this).*

Source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/contracts.html#fallback-function

There is no limit on the fallback function itself. But if it's invoked from another contract though the `transfer()` native function, then the limit is applied.

Example: If you invoke the `fallback()` directly, it succeeds even though it consumes more than 2300 gas. If you invoke it through the `transfer()` function, it fails with "insufficient gas" error as it's only provided 2300 gas units. Comment out the `number = 1` and it will work from the `transfer()` as well (because empty fallback uses less than 2300 gas).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
  uint256 number;

  fallback() external payable {
    number = 1;
  }
}

contract Sender {
  address myContract;

  constructor(address _myContract) {
    myContract = _myContract;
  }

  function invokeFallback() external {
    payable(myContract).transfer(0);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fallback` function is invoked by the EVM under those 2 conditions

- a function that does not exist in contract, gets called, since function does not exist contract is falling back to `fallback` function
- when contract receives `ether` (if you are on etherum, only native token whcih is ether, any other token does not count) `fallback` is called. That is why we have `payable` modifier.

EVM provides 2300 gas. if `fallback` gets called by EVM but it costs more than 2300 gas, the function call will throw an exception and any state change will be reverted.